# Invalid <param> tag (husky simulation)

Tags: simulation, roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I know this have been asked a few times but I have wasted 2 days trying to make this work and still no resolution. I think it's something to do with URDF which I am not very familiar with so any suggestions or help are greatly appreciated!

I am trying to install this package here: [waypoint_nav](https://github.com/nickcharron/waypoint_nav), whilst following the tutorials here: [tutorial](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/husky/HuskyGPSWaypointNav.html)

Whenever I launch `roslaunch outdoor_waypoint_nav outdoor_waypoint_nav_sim.launch`I get this:

```
roslaunch outdoor_waypoint_nav outdoor_waypoint_nav_sim.launch
... logging to /home/arthur/.ros/log/e5783a58-881f-11e8-ace3-08002758e07b/roslaunch-Doge-17757.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
Undefined substitution argument urdf_extras None
when processing file: /opt/ros/kinetic/share/husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro
included from: /home/arthur/catkin_ws/src/waypoint_nav/husky_customization/husky_custom_description/urdf/custom_description.urdf.xacro
included from: /home/arthur/catkin_ws/src/waypoint_nav/husky_customization/husky_custom_gazebo/urdf/custom_description.gazebo.xacro
while processing /home/arthur/catkin_ws/src/waypoint_nav/outdoor_waypoint_nav/launch/include/gazebo.launch:
while processing /home/arthur/catkin_ws/src/waypoint_nav/husky_simulator/husky_gazebo/launch/husky_empty_world.launch:
while processing /home/arthur/catkin_ws/src/waypoint_nav/husky_simulator/husky_gazebo/launch/spawn_husky.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/kinetic/share/xacro/xacro.py '/home/arthur/catkin_ws/src/waypoint_nav/husky_customization/husky_custom_gazebo/urdf/custom_description.gazebo.xacro'     laser_enabled:=true     ur5_enabled:=false     kinect_enabled:=false     ] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(arg husky_gazebo_description)'     laser_enabled:=$(arg laser_enabled)     ur5_enabled:=$(arg ur5_enabled)     kinect_enabled:=$(arg kinect_enabled)     " name="robot_description"/>The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I have looked into the launch and URDF files, I still can't find out what the problem is. Could anyone with more experience please try compiling this package and see how to launch it?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297415/invalid-%3Cparam%3E-tag-(husky-simulation)/) by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2018-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-15**:
Can you replace the screen shot with a copy and paste of the actual text please. Images cannot be searched so are far less useful.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-15**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd, done!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-15**:
Did you set the `robot_description` parameter?

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-15**:
@jayess, no, it's all pulled from github. What I don't understand is why they include husky packages in their github repo and then ask you to install all husky packages from apt-get?

**Comment by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) on 2018-07-15**:
@Hypomania I would suggest deleting the image, as you now have redundant info in the post, and I would suggest adding to the title to indicate it is specific to the husky simulation.

**Comment by [Daniel wan](https://answers.ros.org/users/45219/daniel-wan/) on 2019-08-28**:
I am facing the same problem with you, can you tell me the solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think there are two issues:

1. Listen to the terminal warning and use the `--inorder` option for xacro. See number 12 [here](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) for what the option entails. You should therefore change the `robot_description` param loading in `waypoint_nav/husky_simulator/husky_gazebo/launch/spawn_husky.launch` to

   ```
    <param name="robot_description" 
           command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(arg husky_gazebo_description)'
                    laser_enabled:=$(arg laser_enabled)
                       ur5_enabled:=$(arg ur5_enabled)
                    kinect_enabled:=$(arg kinect_enabled)
                    --inorder
                    " />
   ```
2. If you make change (1), you'll probably then get an error saying there is no xacro macro for `husky_robot`. The `custom_description.urdf.xacro` file, for some reason unknown to me, tries to use a macro for `husky_robot` from the `husky_description` package, even though there doesn't seem to be such a macro in that package (are they maybe using a non-standard husky description?). The `husky.urdf.xacro` file nonetheless includes everything needed to make the robot without the macro, so you just need to comment out line 34 `<xacro:husky_robot />` in `waypoint_nav/husky_customization/husky_custom_description/urdf/custom_description.urdf.xacro`.

---

Originally posted by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) with karma: 642 on 2018-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-15**:
Thank you a lot, I ran grep on the entire repo and the macro was only declared in two places with no further uses, no idea why it's used! Thank you :)

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-15**:
My Gazebo isn't starting without the macro, rviz gives an error to the robot model, have you had any success running it?

**Comment by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) on 2018-07-15**:
I don't see the robot displayed in Gazebo, but I don't think I have all dependencies installed to actually use that package. I do, however, see it successfully come up in rviz without error making only the changes I described.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-15**:
My Gazebo doesn't even start, could be something to do with my VM, thank you however for your help and spotting the redundancy :)

**Comment by [nofear123](https://answers.ros.org/users/39555/nofear123/) on 2019-01-19**:
Hello, I have encountered the same problem as you. Have you solved this problem? How do you solve it?

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-01-19**:
@nofear123, this answer solved my problem :)

**Comment by [SA92](https://answers.ros.org/users/43007/sa92/) on 2019-07-02**:
worked perfectly!

**Comment by [hsaleem](https://answers.ros.org/users/64036/hsaleem/) on 2021-12-02**:
@Hypomania, @SA92, could you please guide me how did you solve the problem?